# Two page recyclerview

Tags: android

I'm thinking of using a ViewPager and a Recyclerview to create [this effect](http://img.wonderhowto.com/img/22/16/63607633122807/0/add-your-own-quick-settings-tiles-android-nougat.w1456.jpg) that has the RecyclerView wrap on two pages with a max number of elements per page.

What would be the best way of achivieng this? I thought to have two separete RecyclerViews for each page and split the List of items between the two RecyclerViews. But it's obvioulsy not the greatest idea.

Comment: I don't think there is another way to do that

Comment: just use `Recyclerview` with two "items", each one is a 3x3 `GridLayout` / `GridView`

Comment: @pskink well I'm using the `Recyclerview` with `GridLayoutManager` for those "items". So I thought that the parent could have been a `ViewPager`.

Comment: no, parent view is `Recyclerview` which has two (or more) children (GridLayout / GridView) each having 3 x 3 grid of items